# how to change colour of button and layout of form in contact form 7 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress for the first time and have no complete knowledge of it.I am using contact form 7 plugin and created a simple contact form but i want to make changes to it according to my site.I tried doing it and went through some videos also and worked accordingly but could'nt make any changes to it.Please help me out.

Comment: can you provide the work you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Publish the form on your site and inspect the elements you want to change (right click -> Inspect), preferably in Google Chrome, open the styles tag and change the CSS rules. When you are satisfied with the new look, copy the new styles in style.css in your theme folder. When you refresh, you'll notice that some styles have applied and that some parts haven't changed. You'll have to add !important next to those styles in your style.css file. I have to note that !important **should be avoided** but sadly when changing some Wordpress plugnis there isn't any other way.